# Problem navigating to a route with Dialogflow and Flutter

Tags: android, json, flutter, dialogflow-es

I am working on an application with Flutter and Dialogflow and I want to make that when I say something specific to the bot, it will take me to a screen. That is, when writing 'depresion', I want it to take me to the context of the id to which 'depresion' corresponds. I have already created an Entitie in Dialogflow 'cual' with the id of the context I want to go to, but now I am not even shown the messages from the bot and it throws me this error.

***UPDATE***
[This is the conversation that I usually have with the bot and it appears before placing the code that appears commented to use the parameters. The idea is that when that "3" appears, it takes me to the context screen that corresponds to that id "3" that I indicate in Navigator.pusnNamed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCvVS.png)

[Flutter error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0b1A.jpg)

[Dialogflow Entitie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dE8py.png)

**class dialog_flow.dart**

```
class FlutterFactsDialogFlow extends StatefulWidget {
  FlutterFactsDialogFlow({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  

  @override
  _FlutterFactsDialogFlowState createState() => new _FlutterFactsDialogFlowState();
}

class _FlutterFactsDialogFlowState extends State<FlutterFactsDialogFlow> {
  final List<FactsMessage> _messages = <FactsMessage>[];
  final TextEditingController _textController = new TextEditingController();
  TtsProvider ttsProvider = TtsProvider();

  Widget _queryInputWidget(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: TextField(
                controller: _textController,
                onSubmitted: _submitQuery,
                decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: "Envia un mensaje"),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
              child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.send),
                  onPressed: () => _submitQuery(_textController.text)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _dialogFlowResponse(context, query) async {
    _textController.clear();
    AuthGoogle authGoogle =
    await AuthGoogle(fileJson: "assets/key.json").build();
    Dialogflow dialogFlow =
    Dialogflow(authGoogle: authGoogle, language: Language.spanish);
    AIResponse response = await dialogFlow.detectIntent(query);
    print(response.queryResult.parameters['cual']);
    int id = int.parse(response.queryResult.parameters['cual']);
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'home', arguments: id);
    FactsMessage message = FactsMessage(
      text: response.getMessage() ??
           CardDialogflow(response.getListMessage()[0]).title,
      name: "PsyBot",
      type: false,
      
    );
    ttsProvider.hablar(response.getMessage());
    setState(() {
      _messages.insert(0, message);
    });
    
  }

  void _submitQuery(String text) {
    _textController.clear();
    FactsMessage message = new FactsMessage(
      text: text,
      name: "Tú",
      type: true,
    );
    setState(() {
      _messages.insert(0, message);
    });
    _dialogFlowResponse(context, text);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("PsyBot"),
      ),
      body: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(
            child: ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              reverse: true, //Para mantener los últimos mensajes al final
              itemBuilder: (_, int index) => _messages[index],
              itemCount: _messages.length,
            )),
        Divider(height: 1.0),
        Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).cardColor),
          child: _queryInputWidget(context),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

**class fact_message.dart**

```
class FactsMessage extends StatelessWidget {
  FactsMessage({this.text, this.name, this.type});

  final String text;
  final String name;
  final bool type;

  List<Widget> botMessage(context) {
    return <Widget>[
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
        child: CircleAvatar(child: Text('Bot')),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(this.name,
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
              child: Text(text),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ];
  }

  List<Widget> userMessage(context) {
    return <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(this.name, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
              child: Text(text),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
        child: CircleAvatar(child: new Text(this.name[0])),
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
      child: new Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: this.type ? userMessage(context) : botMessage(context),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**class home_page.dart**

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  PageController pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  int pageChanged = 0;
  TtsProvider ttsProvider = TtsProvider();
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final preguntaP = Provider.of<PreguntaProvider>(context);
    final int idTest = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home Page'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios), onPressed: (){
            pageController.nextPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 150), curve: Curves.bounceInOut );
          })
        ],
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Pregunta>>(
        future: preguntaP.fetchPreguntas(idTest), 
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Pregunta>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData){
            // ttsprovider
            //ttsProvider.hablar("Prueba");
            List<Pregunta> preg = snapshot.data;
            return PageView(
              physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              pageSnapping: true,
              reverse: false,
              controller: pageController,
              onPageChanged: (index){
                setState(() {
                 pageChanged = index;    

                });
                
              },
              children: armarPreguntas(preg),
              
              );

           
          } else{
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            //return Container();
          }
          
          
        }
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> armarPreguntas(List<Pregunta> listaPreguntas){
    final List<Widget> listadoWidget = [];
    for (Pregunta item in listaPreguntas) {
      listadoWidget.add(Pagina(item, pageController));
    }
    return listadoWidget;
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post and include the content of `response` in line `AIResponse response = await dialogFlow.detectIntent(query);`? So we can clearly see the structure of the response.

Comment: Hello, I just realized why it throws me "null" and it is because when starting the conversation it was saying "hello" which did not correspond to the parameters of the "cual" entitie.

My question is how I can leave that initial conversation and not have to say the parameter when starting the conversation with the bot to go to the screen, how can I condition that if "stress, anxiety or depression" appears during the conversation, it takes me to the screen?

Comment: I see that you figured out the cause of the error. You can post it as an answer to this question. With regards to your new question you might want to check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/contexts-input-output) but I suggest to open a new question since this is another topic. It is also much better to create a new one so the community can contribute :)